# RabbitMQ 3.8.16 Crash Report

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

We are seeing frequent crash with the above error. Could someone please help to find the root cause

CRASH REPORT Process <0.20772.32> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: "stopping because dependent process <0.20770.32> died: shutdown" in gen_server:handle_common_reply/8 line 811

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo36y.png)